# Need suggestion how to solve master page css layout

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

Can you please point me in the right direction?
What I need is pretty much what these two random pages have:
[vmware](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric52/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.8/getting-started)

[chmprocessor](http://chmprocessor.sourceforge.net/)

I need a layout with a header + footer and a left menu.
I am building this in asp.net and in the left sidebar I will have a treeview control.
Maybe use Master page and load user control in the content area or something similar.
I have googled, like: 2 column css layout etc, but it looks like it wont work.

I tried this one: [Netrostar](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-206-How-to-create-ASP.NET-Site-Wide-Layout-Using-Master-Pages)
and some other but I cant enter jsfiddler urls for som reason.

The left menu has problem. If I enter a long text, it will show up in the content area.

So the left sidebar must somehow have a dynamic width.

Since the left sidebar can have need for beeing very wide (if we are looking deep in the treeview hierarchy)
it is pretty convenient to use frames as they do in the two examples above.
But that was not recommended even 10 years ago, I guess.

Im no good at css, so I probably need a working example.
How would you have solved this?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, nobody knows. Fine.
Would it be hard to solve it like Microsoft has?
It can be expanded etc by cliking on it
Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx